# Silverlight Toolkit - how to theme the tick color of a line series chart

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

i am in the middle of theming a Silverlight Line Series chart and for the life of me can't fiure out how to theme the color of the period ticks on my chart

they look great when showing on a light colored background, however on a dark background they are invisible (they are black)

any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks
Doug

Comment: Some time ago, I tried doing an application with Silverlight Toolkit charts and after a few days threw them into the garbage - they are not sensible to use/customize at all. I am using Visifire charts instead and am very happy with them, since they are much easier to use.

Comment: I have finished quite a large project using them successfully for everything - this is the only issue i am having, so changing components now is too late...

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the built-in styles of Silverlight Toolkit charts, you'll see the following:

```
<!--  charting:Chart  -->
<Style TargetType="charting:Chart">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Palette">
        <Setter.Value>
            <datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                <!-- Blue -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Background" GradientOrigin="-0.1,-0.1" Center="0.075,0.015" RadiusX="1.05" RadiusY="0.9">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB9D6F7" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF284B70" Offset="1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                    <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="DataShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- Red -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Background" GradientOrigin="-0.1,-0.1" Center="0.075,0.015" RadiusX="1.05" RadiusY="0.9">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBB7B5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF702828" Offset="1" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                    <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="DataShapeStyle" TargetType="Shape">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
```

The colors come from the Palette property - each new series gets another entry from this palette, as far as I can tell.

Comment: you haven't indicated what part is the "tick" for an interval